# Program not running correctly from task scheduler

Tags: python, windows-7

We have phone recording software running on a windows 7 box. We run a python script that tells a audio converter program sox, to convert the calls to mp3 format.

When we run the script by double clicking it, it works fine. But when we run it through the windows task scheduler, we get the error message.

'Sox is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

Any one have any insight on this issue.

Comment: Specify the full path in the task.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the program's full path or add the proper directory to your environment's PATH variable.

Comment: I added this directory to the PATH C:\Users\Vms Alarms\Desktop\sox.exe

Comment: And this issue still persist.

Comment: Check the user account, under which the program should run.

Answer (score 1):

In the Task Scheduler, click Action tag, and then click Edit, by adding the directory of your program in the "Start in (optional):"  you get rid of the message ".. is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'